# spark custom sort in python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a RDD in Spark (python code below):

```
list1 = [(1,1),(10,100)]
df1 = sc.parallelize(list1)
df1.take(2)
## [(1, 1), (10, 100)]
```

I want to do a custom sort, that compares these tuples based on both entries in the tuple. In python the logic of this compare is something like:

```
# THRESH is some constant
def compare_tuple(a, b):
    center = a[0] - b[0]
    dev = a[1] + b[1]
    r = center / dev
    if r < THRESH:
        return -1
    else if r == THRESH:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

And I would do a custom sort in python as:

```
list1.sort(compare_tuple)
```

How to do this in pyspark? As per the rdd docs:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD

The sortBy method has no custom sort argument.

I see that the scala interface sortBy supports this:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

But I want this in python spark. Any workaround type solutions are also welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always create a custom class and implement rich rich comparison methods:

- pair.py

  ```
  class Pair(tuple):
      def _cmp(self, other):
          center = self[0] - other[0]
          dev = self[1] + other[1]
          r = center / dev if dev != 0 else center
          if r < 0:
              return -1
          if r >  0:
              return 1
          return 0

      def __lt__(self, other):
          return self._cmp(other) < 0

      def __lte__(self, other):
          return self._cmp(other) <= 0

      def __eq__(self, other):
          return self._cmp(other) == 0

      def __ge__(self, other):
          return self._cmp(other) >= 0

      def __gt__(self, other):
          return self._cmp(other) > 0
  ```
- main script

  ```
  from pair import Pair

  sc.addPyFile("pair.py")

  rdd = sc.parallelize([(1, 1),(10, 100), (-1, 1), (-1, -0.5)]).map(Pair)
  rdd.sortBy(lambda x: x).collect()
  ## [(-1, 1), (-1, -0.5), (1, 1), (10, 100)]
  ```

but if `dev` is a standard deviation then it doesn't affect the outcome and you can safely sort by identity using plain tuples or `keyfunc` which extracts `centers` (`lambda x x:[0]`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! dev is indeed meant to represent a standard deviation. However, it shouldn't be ignorable even when always positive. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Your answer looks perfect! Will try out your code and get back on this.

Comment: Yeah, that works. I guess I still hadn't wrapped my head around the fact that a RDD stores python objects in a manner that permits use of their methods. Thanks again!